# reading a file through input streams in java

Tags: java-io

how is the flow of execution directed in the code below.(how does 'i' get updated(or incremented)?

```
while((i=fr.read())!=-1)
{ System.out.print((char)i);
}
```

- See more at: http://tutorialspointexamples.com/filereader-and-filewriter-in-java/#sthash.QxSyiKRe.dpuf

Answer (score 1):

Filereader.read reads a single character. It returns an int, which represents the character read.

in your code

```
while((i=fr.read())!=-1)
{ 
   System.out.print((char)i);
}
```

(i=fr.read()) resolves first, giving you the character read. The while loop will resolve this each time it loops, moving through the file.

The outer while then compares this value against -1.

- If it does, the while loop ends.
- If it doesn't match it outputs the character.

Comment: but how does the loop proceed since there is no updation for the counter variable( in this case i) in the loop.

Comment: i isn't a counter variable. i is the value that is returned by the read call. fr has an internal file pointer - read just tells it to read the next character. see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_filereader_class.htm

Comment: @pradeep in other words, when there are no more characters to read, `i` would be set to `-1`, and the loop would terminate